# How from dict of list create list of dict

Tags: python

I have `dict`:

```
D = {'a': ['1a', '2a', '3a'], 'c': ['1c', '2c', '3c'], 'b': ['1b', '2b', '3b']}
```

I want to convert `D` to `list` of `dict`:

```
L = [{'a':'1a', 'b': '1b', 'c': '1c'}, {'a':'2a', 'b': '2b', 'c': '2c'}, ...]
```

I tried:

```
>>> l = [(k, v) for k, vals in D.items() for v in vals]
>>> map(dict, zip(*zip(*[iter(l)]*4)))
[{'a': '1a', 'c': '1c', 'b': '1b'}, {'a': '2a', 'c': '2c', 'b': '2b'}, ...
```

I need more readable solution.

Comment: Dicts don't preserve order, for that use an ordereddict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
L = [dict(zip(D.keys(), vals)) for vals in zip(*D.values())]
```

Output:

```
>>> print L
[{'a': '1a', 'c': '1c', 'b': '1b'}, 
 {'a': '2a', 'c': '2c', 'b': '2b'}, 
 {'a': '3a', 'c': '3c', 'b': '3b'}]
```